# How to ensure a Sveltekit project can actually run on Cloudflare workers?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

[Sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) and [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/) seem to be a great match. My objective is to deliver well-tested code, that runs smoothly on Cloudflare pages/workers. To do this, I use Cypress.io for e2e testing. The problem is that I can't trust the tests running locally, as using any Node.js API works fine locally (for example `Buffer.from`). But this code **breaks** the site when deploying to Cloudflare.

**How can I run the Sveltekit project locally to ensure it will work once deployed?**

As a bonus, would it somehow be possible to configure the typescript project so it would throw errors when accessing Node.js API's? According to [this](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/learning/how-workers-works/) Cloudflare page, workers are running a v8 instance. We are using the "official" [adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

SvelteKit is planning ways to make this easier in the long-term. You can hear Rich talk a bit about this [in the most recent Svelte NYC meetup](https://youtu.be/s6a1pbTVcUs?t=2129).

In the meantime, your best bet is to include something like a `"postbuild"` hook that points [`miniflare`](https://miniflare.dev/) to the output file that SK produced. This will ensure that the contents are bootable according to a Cloudflare Workers emulated environment. You can run an e2e test suite against the `localhost` endpoint it spawns for you, too.

Comment: Wait? That would be genious. I will try out the miniflare and report back :)

Comment: When I try using miniflare like this with the `@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare` what file should I point miniflare to?